# Unable to activate httparty-0.13.7, because json-2.0.4 conflicts with json (~> 1.8)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, rubygems, httparty

I am trying to run a script and in my two files i have the following

bot.rb

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'active_support'
require 'active_support/core_ext'
require './app/jobs/scraping_job.rb'

puts 'Hello World'
```

scraping_job.rb

```
require 'httparty'

class ScrapingJob

end
```

in my gemfile, i have also added `gem 'httparty'`.

But when i run my script i hit this error

```
Unable to activate httparty-0.13.7, because json-2.0.4 conflicts with json (~> 1.8) (Gem::ConflictError).
```

How can i solve this error?

Comment: I would a) make sure all the gems you need (directly) are in your Gemfile, and b) run `bundle update`. If this will not solve it, it would normally show you more details about dependency conflicts. If it does not, please paste your Gemfile, could be helpful for our debugging.

Answer (score 1):

your can run

```
bundle update json
```

make sure you type json, don't just bundle update, also if there is apps that depend with json 1.8 you can update as well for example kgio then you can type

```
bundle update json kgio
```